# Python -- Struggling to understand how to update function, as variable in while loop is updated

Tags: python

Highlighted in Bold(the while loop) is the area I'm struggling with. I understand that what's happening is I've initialized the function fictional_cost with the initial guess variable. What I'd like to have happen is, as I perform a bisection search, for the updated variable to be used to re-call said function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
low = 0

high = 10000

annual_salary = float(input("Please enter your annual salary:"))

monthly_salary = float(annual_salary / 12)

guess = (high + low) / 2.0

def fictional_cost(n):
    global months
    global current_savings
    global annual_salary
    global monthly_salary
    while months < 36:
        rcurrent_savings = float(current_savings * (r / 12))
        current_savings = float(rcurrent_savings + (monthly_salary * n) + current_savings)
        months += 1
        if months % 6 == 0:
            annual_salary = annual_salary * float(1 + semi_annual_raise)
            monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
    return current_savings


**while abs(fictional_cost(n)- total_cost) >= epsilon:
   if fictional_cost(guess) < total_cost:
        low = guess
    else:
        high = guess
    guess = (high + low)/2.0
    num_guesses += 1**




print("Your best savings rate is:" + str(guess) + "!")
print("Performed in" + str(num_guesses)+
"steps!")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Comment: Hello DorrenRy, welcome to stackoverflow. Its a little unclear what isnt working / or deviating from your expected behaviour. Could you clarify or post the error you're getting when executing this function?

Answer (score 0):

PS: I dont have a way to comment to your question. So using the answer section to respond.

I am trying to answer the question. It looks like you have not assigned a value for n.

I am unable to find the value of n in your code.

Can you explain where you are defining the value of n please. Highlighted in bold.

```
while abs(fictional_cost(**n**)- total_cost) >= epsilon:
```

My assumption is that you are trying to check with the value of guess instead of n. So your while loop should be as follows:

```
while abs(fictional_cost(guess)- total_cost) >= epsilon:
```

Comment: Yeah stack auto-corrected guess to n. The issue is that I get a reoccuring loop of one value for fictional_cost.

Comment: Without the values for these variables, it is difficult to troubleshoot the code. I have added the following as default values before we get into the code. 

    months = 16
    current_savings = 20000
    r = 6
    semi_annual_raise = 10000
    total_cost = 100
    epsilon = 100
    num_guesses = 0

Answer (score 0):

There are several variables in your code which look undefined (e.g. r) but I'm not going to focus on these as they aren't the focus of your question.

If I've understood your requirements correctly, this should work:

```
x = fictional_cost(guess)
while (x - total_cost) >= epsilon:
       if x < total_cost:
        low = guess
    else:
        high = guess
    guess = (high + low)/2.0
    num_guesses += 1
    x = fictional_cost(guess)
```

If this answer doesn't work exactly, it might be that I've misunderstood some of your variables so try playing around with it a little, or add some more detail to your question. If you add more detail, I'll refine my answer if I can.

Comment: No problem @DorrenRy! If the answer did work for you, you can click the 'tick' icon to accept it as the correct answer. This will make the answer easier for other users to find if they have the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using references in function parameters. String, whole numbers and tuples are call by value. Try using mutable objects as changing their values anywhere in the scope will reflect it everywhere in scope.